# Is there a verb for remaining silent?

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs, phrase-requests, translation

Dutch has the verb *zwijgen*, which means *remaining silent*. *Ik zwijg* means *I remain silent* or *I say nothing*.  It is also often used as an imperative, similar to *shut up*.

I have been discussing this with some native English speakers who have sound understanding of Dutch, and we couldn't come up with a verb in English.

Does it exist?

Comment: There is in French, as well, but not in English. Google translate translates *se taire* as *"shut up", "keep mum", "hold one's tongue"*. *Le Dictionnaire Larousse* translates it as *"to keep quiet"* or *"to fall silent"*.

Comment: *To silence* is a verb. "I silence myself" is not too far removed. @PeterShor - are you thinking of *se taire*? I don't see how that is very different from *Silence yourself!*

Comment: Google translate also mentions "hush", but to me that sounds more like keeping a secret then to "shut up"

Comment: @medica you are right! You should put that in as an answer for me to accept http://www.the-conjugation.com/english/verb/silence.php Funny, the answer was just smiling at me from the beginning.

Comment: @Andra You would not actually say e.g. "he silenced" to indicate "he remained quiet" though. It might indicate he became quiet from a position of previously making noise in context though.

Comment: Keep in mind that, as a verb, *to silence* means *to make (one) silent,* not *to be silent.*  Sometimes the noun *silence* is used by itself as a quasi-imperative: i.e. as short for *I demand silence!*

Comment: "No comment" is what people say to reporters asking questions. This appears to be close to the OP context of *Ik zwijg*. In American court-room dramas they usually say "I invoke the [fifth amendment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fifth_Amendment_to_the_United_States_Constitution)" when they refuse to answer a question.

Comment: *"To shut the hell up"* if you want to get really technical about it.

Comment: There appears to be no such verb in modern English, but there are obsolete or archaic verbs: the OED lists _to hust_ (last quotations from 16th century), _to swie_ (last quotations from 13th century), and _to hist_ (poetic, last quotations from 19th century). There is also the current dialect word _to whisht_ (or _wheesht_), already mentioned in answers.

Comment: The Dutch word "zwijgen" actually means something similar to the English word "refrain", meaning to fail to act.

Comment: @firtydank Not in the Dutch I speak. There refrain is more covered by *inhouden*

Comment: @Andra - I see. I speak Afrikaans rather than Dutch, where the word "swyg" is used. "Swyg" could also mean to "give in", as in "swyg onder die argument" (gave in to the argument). I just assumed it would carry the same meaning as "zwijgen".

Comment: An an imperative, *shush*, *hush*, or *shhh* are normally used.

Comment: @firtydank That must be a form of the Dutch word "bezwijken". I'm guessing "swyg" is said with a "k" at the end, where "zwijg" ends in the typical hard Dutch "g". (Kind of a late comment I know, but oh well)

Answer (score 23):

There is no single word to capture exactly what you're looking for.

First, the difficulties with some suggestions. You're looking for a single word for 'to remain silent'. Forcing in to a single word, the semantic nearby shorter terms don't really capture this well.

- 'To silence' is a transitive verb — someone is making someone else be quiet. You can say 'to silence oneself' but that has a special ring to it, a very active restraint, too forceful.
- 'Hush' is a command — it is rare in the non-imperative and then it is a transitive like 'to silence'.
- 'Shut up' is very much a command like 'hush' and is a bit forceful and rude.

---

Now for the closest 'way' to say it. The translation of German 'schweigen'/Dutch 'zwijgen'/French 'se taire' is matched best by

> 'to keep quiet' or 'to remain quiet'.

which is an intransitive statement of state. For example:

> "I was told it was a secret so I kept quiet"
>
> "If my boss brings up the incident I'll remain quiet"

Other more colloquial phrasings are 'to keep ones mouth shut' or 'to keep mum'. All these can be used in an imperative manner but don't have to be.

Comment: 'to silence' is to make a thing become silent, not to make it be silent or remain silent.

Answer (score 11):

In British English, *schtum* is an **informal** adjective used to mean remaining silent, e.g.:

> It's for the best if nobody hears about any of this business, so if you're asked, make sure to keep schtum.

Although I've personally never heard it used as such, according to Oxford Dictionaries.com [*schtum* can also be used as a verb](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/shtum):

> Be or become quiet and non-communicative

The definition page provides a few examples, but I think the following is the most apt to the case provided in the question:

> The possible risk being that she schtums and won't tell me the truth or just laughs in my face when I bring it up because it's apparently trivial.

This usage in the active voice sounds pretty jarring to my ear, though. Although I'd probably still think it an unusual word-choice, another example taken from Oxford Dictionaries.com utilising the passive voice sounds far more idiomatic:

> This source was schtummed when Julia posted a scathing rebuke on the thread, really very angry.

The word *schtum* on its own can also be used in the imperative/as an interjection:

> Schtum!

Used as an imperative, *schtum* is not directly equivalent to the example of *shut-up* given in the question (in the sense of an interjectory command for "Silence!"). Its meaning is more akin to "keeping quiet" about something in the sense of not releasing information.

Comment: How would you pronounce schtum?

Comment: Very interesting. I've never heard this word before.

Comment: This is unknown in AmE. That is to say that if you used it in the US no one would know what you're talking about.

Comment: @Mitch, now that you know about it are you going to keep schtum or spill the beans ?

Comment: It's a German (or possibly Yiddish) loanword: *stumm*, adjective, pronounced /ʃtʊm/.

Comment: @Frank, I won't keep mum about it.

Comment: @Andra I don't know the IPA (well not one, anyway) so I can't transcribe the pronunciation, and I can't think of an another word that reliably rhymes with *schtum*, so I'm afraid I don't know how I can convey the pronunciation :(

Comment: @Andra the audio & the IPA are in the first link, schtum /ʃtʊm/.

Answer (score 11):

> [hush](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/hush) (hʌʃ)
>   interj., v. hushed, hush•ing,
>   n. interj.
>
> 1. (used as a command to be silent or quiet.)
>      v.i.
> 2. to become or be silent or quiet.
>      v.t.
> 3. to make silent; silence.
> 4. to suppress mention of; keep concealed (often fol. by up): to hush up a scandal.
> 5. to calm, quiet, or allay: to hush someone's fears.
>      n.
> 6. silence or quiet, esp. after noise; stillness.
>
> [1350–1400; appar. back formation from husht whist2 (Middle English huissht), the -t being taken for past participle suffix]
>
> *Random House Kernerman Webster's College Dictionary, © 2010 K Dictionaries Ltd. Copyright 2005, 1997, 1991 by Random House, Inc. All rights reserved.*

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/There's_a_Kind_of_Hush

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RjSkUlhuJ3s

Comment: There's also _shush_ and a Scottish version _wheesht_ which I suspect sounds more like the Middle English _huissht_.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hushpuppy#Etymology

Comment: And don't forget the shorter [_shh_](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mlv7Bp-L2MM)!

Answer (score 10):

"tacet" verb

To silence, or remain quiet

[from Latin: it is silent, from tacēre  to be quiet]

Comment: @kjhughes Ah, apologies. But this is a good example of why it's good to link to references.

Comment: Could do with a link, not sure tacet is a word, it's closest is tacit, which means something entirely different.

Comment: @Darryl kjhughes supplied a link above. Though that indicates it is exclusively a musical direction.

Comment: This answer looks like a quote from somewhere. Is it a quote? Where is it from? Always cite your sources. Mods are instructed to delete on sight any material that's not properly attributed.

Comment: I've seen this used in the context of sheet music - if a particular instrument doesn't play anything during a movement of a larger piece, it may just read "tacet" instead of writing out the movement as nothing but rests.

Answer (score 4):

Consider *keep mum* and *mum's the word*.

> [keep mum](http://www.allwords.com/word-keep+mum.html): do not talk; especially keep silent about something that may be sensitive or secret
>
> [mum's the word](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mum%27s_the_word): *(Idiom)* keep quiet; say nothing

Also, *quiesce* might fit.

> [quiesce](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/quiesce): to become quiet or quieter; fall silent: *The audience quiesced as the speaker entered*

Comment: Mum's the word.... is the moment, of the silence (sung to the tune of Grease).

Answer (score 3):

*Mute* can be used as a verb. In ordinary English it normally means to deaden a sound rather than to completely silence it ("the response from the Japanese was muted"), but since almost every remote control on the planet has a mute button which silences all sound, one could use it to mean "to silence".

Comment: But that's different from "to remain silent".

Answer (score 3):

One of the older senses of "demur" is to hesitate or refuse to speak about something because one disagrees with it, but I'm not sure that's the word you're looking for.

Comment: Is "Dim it!" related and used?

Comment: I don't think it's related, and I can't say I've ever heard it used.

Answer (score 3):

Another command meaning "silence yourself" is *dummy up*.

*Dummy up* defined at Dictionary.com: Informal. to keep silent; refuse to answer: If anybody asks you, just dummy up.

Comment: "*Clam up*" also suggests itself.

Answer (score 2):

To *silence* is a verb:

> To make silent or bring to silence.

In thinking about the French (se taire?), there is a pronoun associated with the verb; *tais-toi* is *silence yourself*.

It's not a single word, but it is a verb, much like the French.

There is also [quieten](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/quieten)tr. & intr.v. Chiefly British

> To make or become quiet.

Comment: But the question is about remaining silent not becoming silent.

Comment: +1 this is what I thought of myself.  It also meets the criteria of being an imperative to "shut up", i.e. silence!

Answer (score 1):

There are many different ways, depending on whether it's someone being *told* or *ordered* to be silent (*Hush, Shut up, Silence, Be quiet, Quiet down, Put a sock in it, Shhh*, etc.) or whether they're voluntarily being silent, and at that, willingly or out of fear (*I'll be quiet, My lips are sealed*, etc.). Someone or an animal may be *quieted* or *silenced*. An inanimate device may be *muted* or the volume *turned down*.

In the US, you may hear the expression "I take the Fifth". This is in reference to the Fifth Amendment to the Constitution, which gives you the right to not incriminate yourself (be silent about some accusation). Of course, anyone who actually *says* that is immediately presumed guilty (by most people) of whatever they're accused of, by simply taking the Fifth.

Comment: Per http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/a/364 for the use–mention distinction, please use an italic face not a bold one. It makes the page look too heavy otherwise, and furthermore runs counter to typographic convention both on this cite and in scholarly works.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say "mum", as "He was mum about the incident."

Comment: Shouldn't that be "*He [**kept mum**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/keep+mum) about the incident*"?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why no one has really mentioned this yet:

The word is indeed ***quiet***.

When telling someone to stop making noise and remain silent, many times people will simply say ***"Quiet."*** In a fuller sentence, people sometimes say ***"I quieted the dog."***

Likewise, people use quiet to refer to themselves or another who did not make noise for a time. They might say ***"I quieted."*** It is grammatically correct, but feels clunky; I personally wouldn't say it like that, but as ***"I quieted down"*** More naturally in speech, people usually say ***"I was quiet."*** In this sense, however, quiet is actually an adjective, but I would bet that this dutch word, zwijgen, would be translated as such, depending on the context, because it is more familiar.

Comment: _Zwijgen_ is not “more appropriately labeled an adjective because it is describing a noun”. It is a verb, pure and simple. It conjugates as a verb, and it doesn’t describe any noun. To be silent is an _action_ in languages like Dutch, unlike in English. _Quiet_ in English is not an answer to the question because it is not a verb that means ‘to be silent’. It is either an adjective, or a verb that means ‘to _make_ silent’.

Comment: @Janus I don't speak Dutch. I was going off what the OP wrote: "Dutch has the verb *zwijgen* which means *remaining silent*. *Ik zwijg* means *I remain silent* or *I say nothing*." Whether the word conjugates or not, the OP presented what looks like an adjective to me. Quiet is used as a verb and an adjective. I merely pointed out that this dutch word seems to do the same. I made an edit to address this.

Answer (score 0):

To speak is an act one could [*desist from*](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/desisting). [Cease-and-desist](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cease_and_desist) letters are often used to silence people for copyright and slander reasons.

> Zwijgen. Ik zwijg. Zwijg!
>
> Desisting. I desist. Desist!

"Stop" works better, but also better than "zwijgen".

Actions speak louder than words.

Comment: 'Stop' and 'desist' work for any activity, not just speech, and the OP is just looking for something about speech.

Comment: Refusal is the only thing i could think of; silencing and quieting require an object.

Answer (score 0):

I'll bite my tongue

I'll keep that under my hat

I'll keep that to myself

all could mean to remain silent depending on the circumstance